# Open desktop applications with javascript from the browser

Tags: javascript

I don’t know if this is possible. Anyways onto the question. I’m coding a game using JavaScript.
I’m new to Js and I most literally do not know much.
I’m looking for a method of opening up a window (no browser) like video games when you click on them.
Anyone know what I should do?

Edit: Example. If you click on Minecraft, it brings up a window, so does unity, or file explorer (just examples), I want to be able to do that but with my game.

Answer (score 3):

This is called a modal, linked is a guide to create a simple modal.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: Thank you, but I looked it up and the modal doesn’t look like the solution to my question. But thank you anyways. I should’ve been more clear with my question. I edited the question btw if you want to read it again! Thank you!

Comment: @DiamondHeadphones do you mean a window that you can drag around close and minimize within the page?

Comment: I do not want to use html or a browser. Correct me if I'm wrong. If I go to my desktop screen and double click on a video game like Minecraft, It would open into a new window so I could play. that's the window I want.

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible without some kind of companion program installed on the system. You can use links to open steam games and some other games (epic games). But there's not really a way to launch desktop apps from the browser.

Comment: Ok, thank you anyways! If you do happen to find out a way be sure to answer this question or reply back. Thank you!!!

Comment: @DiamondHeadphones you are talking about opening them from a web page right? Because this is definitely possible if your using node.js.